# pyarrow fails to import when calling a pandas_udf on a spark YARN cluster, while it can be imported directly in an interactive pyspark session

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I am using `pyspark` on a remote YARN cluster. I can create interactive jupyter notebook sessions using [sparkmagic](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic), or execute jobs using a tool that, in turn, sends the jobs using `spark-submit`.

OS and libraries available on this cluster are quite old, but I have no way to update them. I've been trying to ship personal and third-party packages that I would like to use through tar'ed virtualenvs as described in spark [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html#using-virtualenv). So far this works fairly well as long as I force the `numpy` version on the built environments to be the same as the one that is installed on the cluster.

At the beginning of my session, I enable arrow and load my virtual environment using

```py
import sys
import os
from os import path

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled", "true")
sc = spark.sparkContext

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/"))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "venv/lib/python3.6/"))
```

Then, if I execute

```py
import pyarrow as pa
```

inside a notebook cell, I get no error message. However, if I try to execute the following example (inspired by saprk [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/sql/arrow_pandas.html#pandas-udfs-a-k-a-vectorized-udfs))

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

@pandas_udf(IntegerType(), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def slen(s):
    return s.str.len()

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([[1, "dasads"], [4, "1w"]], columns=["col1", "col2"]))
df.select(slen("col2")).show()
```

this raises a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o185.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, dtkigsa103.b0358, executor 3): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hadoop8/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1644417834083_1514/container_e40_1644417834083_1514_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 242, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/hadoop8/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1644417834083_1514/container_e40_1644417834083_1514_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 144, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/hadoop8/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1644417834083_1514/container_e40_1644417834083_1514_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 132, in read_single_udf
    return arg_offsets, wrap_scalar_pandas_udf(func, return_type)
  File "/hadoop8/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1644417834083_1514/container_e40_1644417834083_1514_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 80, in wrap_scalar_pandas_udf
    arrow_return_type = to_arrow_type(return_type)
  File "/hadoop8/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1644417834083_1514/container_e40_1644417834083_1514_01_000004/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1613, in to_arrow_type
    import pyarrow as pa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec$$anon$2.<init>(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec.evaluate(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any thoughts on what could cause the import error and how to fix this ?

I've tried changing pyarrow version to 0.10 and 0.9 (seems like 0.8 is the minimal version in order to get it to work with spark)

Here is what I put in the env requirements (corresponds to installed numpy on the cluster):

```
install_requires=
    numpy==1.12.1
    scipy==1.2.3
    pandas==0.24.2
    pyarrow==0.9.0
```

Comment: You need to make sure pyarrow is installed in **all the nodes**, not just driver node

Comment: @pltc thanks, can you elaborate on how I can achieve this ? As I said, I do not have direct access to the cluster but can ship a virtualenv when opening a spark session. Again, `import pyarrow as pa` alone works, I would have guessed this meant that the import operation succeeded on the nodes.